# Pass data from class running in the background to an activity currently running

Tags: android, android-activity

Basically I have socket classes running in the background of an activity I'm running which was initialized by the activity. What happens is that, a computer on the socket.io server can send me a message logged onto the android app which I'm able to receive in the callback, however I would like to pass that message to the currently running activity, so I can use an intent. since that will start the activity back up again. So this is what I tried.

```
@Override
    public void on(String event, IOAcknowledge ack, Object... data) {
       // if((JSONObject) data[0]!=null)
        //callback.on(event, (JSONObject) data[0]);
        System.out.println("Server triggered event '" + event + "'");
        //Log.d("Message","Yeah");
        if (event.equals("message")) {
        System.out.println(data[2]);
        //System.out.println("Server sent this '" + data.getString("message") + "'");
        Chat chatter=new Chat();
        chatter.getMsg((String)data[2]);
        }
    }
```

This is the method that receives the callback. As you can see I called a method on the running activity to  pass the data. Here is it.

```
public void getMsg(String mssg){
        //System.out.println(mssg);
        HashMap mapper=new HashMap();
        mapper.put("message"mssg);
        mapper.put("name","them");
        chatList.add(mapper);
        //connect.start(msg);
        ListAdapter adapter =new SimpleAdapter(
                Chat.this, chatList,
                R.layout.chat_view, new String[]{"message","name"},
                new int[]{R.id.senderchatMessage, R.id.senderchatName}
                );
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        //return msg;
    }
```

This method is in the activity. However I get an error that says IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()  which I really don't understand what it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Chat` is an Activity, doing the following is not good:

```
Chat chatter = new Chat();
```

My suggestion is bit of a workaround and may not be considered good practice(or may not even work).

Create a static variable mContext in your Activity class:

```
public static Context mContext;

....

....

// set it up in your onCreate()
mContext = Chat.this;
```

Make these changes:

```
@Override
public void on(String event, IOAcknowledge ack, Object... data) {
   // if((JSONObject) data[0]!=null)
    //callback.on(event, (JSONObject) data[0]);
    System.out.println("Server triggered event '" + event + "'");
    //Log.d("Message","Yeah");
    if (event.equals("message")) {
    System.out.println(data[2]);
    //System.out.println("Server sent this '" + data.getString("message") + "'");

    Intent newIntent = new Intent(Chat.mContext, Chat.class);

    newIntent.putExtra("MSG", (String)data[2]);

    Chat.mContext.startActivity(newIntent);

    }
}
```

This intent will be intercepted by the `onNewIntent()` method of `Chat` activity if it is running. You'll need to override it.

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    if (intent.hasExtra("MSG")) {
        // Retrieve the message and call getMsg(String)
        getMsg(intent.getStringExtra("MSG"));  // Use the same key as before
    }
}
```

See if this works for you.

Comment: Wait a minute. Is mContent of type Context? You forgot to clarify.

Comment: @MichaelNana Nice catch, fixing it now. Careful about `mContext`, I had misspelled it as `mContent` a couple of times above.

Comment: Yeah so I tried it out. Well it starts a new intent but I don't get the message. Also I don't want to start a new intent because I want the data pushed to the current activity and not starting a new one. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: @MichaelNana A new activity will not started. Only the onNewIntent() of the running activity will be called. But it seems that ain't working. Is a new activity being created?

Comment: Yeah, that's what happened.

Comment: @MichaelNana Ok, you'll need to add `android:launchMode="singleTask"` to this activity in your project's manifest.

Comment: @MichaelNana Hey, that's great, I wasn't sure if this would work.

Answer (score 0):

it might be you are updating your UI in another thread rather than your UI thread which is now allowed, so try to run your UI code in `runOnUiThread()` method

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
      // your ui code
     }
   });
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. However that won't work because the class that is trying to pass the data is not an activity.

Comment: hımm can you pass a context object to that class? if you can that kinda might work out